# laravel 8 how to select not null on pivot table using hasMany

Tags: laravel, pivot, pivot-table, laravel-8, laravel-7

i will make it simple i want to select all the `users` where that have a **data** not `null`

like this in photo the **ID 1** has a `users data` but the others **ID** like **ID 2, 3 ,4**  don't have a `users data` it's `NULL` or `[] or empty Array`

[image]

but i don't have a idea what kind of query to achieve that goal and i don't have a idea where to put that code **CONTROLLER or MODEL?**

so here is my **CONTROLLER**

```
  public function index()
    {
        return  Project::with('users')->get();
    }
```

here is my **MODEL Project**

```
   public function users(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)
     ->withPivot('salary')->
     ->using(project_user::class);
   }
```

hopefully you can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
 Project::whereHas('users')->with('users')->get();
```

Comment: yes like this, but i want still to show the data of id 2, 3, 4. it is possible to do that?